# MongoDB - Adding multiple entries on multiple schema/models by one entry

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to find a way to make one entry and have several seperate schemas by one insert command.

heres a sample array

```
{
    title: "yay",

    property1:{
        title:"yay"
    },

    property2:{
        title: "yay"
    }
}
```

heres what i want to do

```
DB.create(array)
```

heres what i want in return

db has one item with a string and 2 seperate objectid as reference for another schema

edit :

The purpose of this question was to make one entry with one schema or a function that would create documents in multiple schemas. I was really wrong with this approach because a SINGLE type of entry is what a schema does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to make entries on multiple SCHEMAS while creating through a single SCHEMA - to achieve this the only way is to promisify the entire thing.

```
Product.create(product)
.then((productEntry) => { Customer.create(productEntry.customer) })
.then((something) => { shipping.create(something.address) })
```

By promisifying and chaining the entire journey of the incoming data i was able to handle my problem very efficiently.